# C - Function has internal linkage but is not defined

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

I have this folder structure:

[image: structure]

I wrote a simple function to test the folder structure, for seen if all header file but when I compile with the make command, I have this error:

> warning: function 'stampa' has internal linkage but is not defined

I the `lagrange.h` file I have this:

```
#ifndef LAGRANGE_H

static void stampa(int i);

#endif /* LAGRANGE_H */
```

and in the `lagrange.c` file I have this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <stdio.h>

void stampa(int i){
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

in the end, int `main.c` I simply call the function `stampa` passing them a number.

Comment: Aside: you forgot to put `#define LAGRANGE_H` in `lagrange.h`

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from `lagrange.h`

Comment: And it's good practice to include the header file in the corresponding .c file. So there should be a `#include "lagrange.h"` in lagrange.c.

Comment: `static` when defining a function means "in this source file only." If you put it in a header it is either meaningless, or it creates a new copy of the function in every file that includes it. Not something that you want.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### **Explanation of the error:**

The compilation error occurs because:

1. You have declared a function with `static` keyword (i.e. with internal linkage) inside `lagrange.h`
2. And you have included this file `lagrange.h` in `main.c` file different from `lagrange.c`, where the function is not defined.

So when the compiler compiles `main.c` file, it encounters the `static` declaration without any associated definition, and raises logically the error. The error message is explicit.

### Solution:

In your case the solution is to remove the `static` keyword, because `static` means that the function can be called only in the .c file where it is defined, which is not your case.
Moreover, a good practice may be to declare any `static` function in the same .c file where it is defined, and not in .h file.

Comment: Don't forget that putting things in the anonymous namespace also makes it file static. e.g., `namespace { ... }` is only visible to that code translation unit.

Comment: @JesseChisholm that's only relevant to C++, but the OP is talking about C